# JSP pagination without retrieving the whole result set?

Tags: jsp, pagination

I need to display the log entries from a database.
Of course the log data is huge, so I have to show the results on several pages, and that **without** getting **all** the log data at once, but as the user navigates through the pages.

I know about [DisplayTag](http://displaytag.sourceforge.net/11/) and [TableTags](http://code.google.com/p/tabletags/), but it seems to me that they both fetch all the data before applying pagination.

Before I start developing my own JSP tag, does anyone know of a 3rd party solution for this problem?

Thanks,
Marius

Answer (score 3, accepted):

About DisplayTag: it does support [Value List](http://displaytag.sourceforge.net/11/tut_externalSortAndPage.html) design pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Inside your JSP is not really the good place to solve the whole problem.
In a typical layered approach, you separate the presentation (JSP here) from the data access (where you do your query).

Your displaytag/jsp tag should pass to the data access layer which page it wants (eg I need the next 30 and am on page 5), and your data access layer then takes care of a paginated query.

Answer (score 1):

Best solution on this is [Jmesa](http://code.google.com/p/jmesa)